# indexing json with json value in elasticsearch

Tags: json, xml, elasticsearch

I am trying to index a document in elasticsearch.  The json I have comes from the document being transformed from XML to JSON. It is valid JSON.  Looks like this:

```
    {
        "shortcasename": {
            "_attributes": {
                "party1": "People",
                "party2": "Johnson"
            },
            "_children": [
                "People",
                {
                    "connector": {
                        "_attributes": {
                            "normval": "v"
                        },
                        "_children": [
                            " v. "
                        ]
                    }
                },
                "Johnson"
            ]
        }
    }
```

Elasitcsearch seems to have a problem with the shortcasename._children.  The error I get is:

```
{
   "error": {
      "root_cause": [
         {
            "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
            "reason": "failed to parse"
         }
      ],
      "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
      "reason": "failed to parse",
      "caused_by": {
         "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
         "reason": "mapper [shortcasename._children] of different type,      current_type [string], merged_type [ObjectMapper]"
      }
   },
   "status": 400
}
```

Is there a way to get the json to be indexed the way it is?

Answer (score 0):

The JSON you have has a conflict with the `_children` field:

```
{
  "shortcasename": {
    "_attributes": {
      "party1": "People",
      "party2": "Johnson"
    },
    "_children": [
      "People",
      {
        "connector": {
          "_attributes": {
            "normval": "v"
          },
          "_children": [
            " v. "
          ]
        }
      },
      "Johnson"
    ]
  }
}
```

The top-level `_children` field is an array containing a mix of objects (`{"connector": ...}`) and strings (`"People"`, "`Johnson"`). Elasticsearch doesn't support that, that's why it complains that it cannot merge `string` and `Object`